# Idiomatic way of assigning element of boost::mpl vector_c at index

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

I have

```
mpl::vector_c<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>
```

I wand to 'assign' the element at position 3, say I want to set it to 30. Therefore, I have to write
a meta-function taking and index, the vector and the new value and returning the modified sequence.
I ended up with the following solution

```
template <int k, class sequence, class value>
class assign_element
{
            typedef typename mpl::begin<sequence>::type begin;
            typedef typename mpl::advance<begin, mpl::int_<k> >::type pos;
            typedef typename mpl::erase <sequence, pos>::type sequence2;

            typedef typename mpl::begin<sequence2>::type begin2;
            typedef typename mpl::advance<begin2, mpl::int_<k> >::type pos2;
public:
            typedef typename mpl::insert <sequence2, pos2, value>::type type;
};
```

and then i use it as follows

```
typedef mpl::vector_c<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5> sequence;
typedef typename assign_element<3, sequence, mpl::int_<30> >::type result;
```

This solution works, but as you can see it is quite involved (involves iterators, advance ...). 
There exist a simpler and possibly efficient solution to this use case ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I never used MPL, but it looks quite interesting and I take a look at the doc. Here my 3 answers, I hope this helps you:

1) Wrong answer - however maybe good start for finding a right one. Do you consider to use replace_if?

```
typedef vector_c<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5> sequence;
typedef replace_if< numbers, equal_to<_,int_<3> >, int_<30> >::type result;
```

You would need a at_pos<3> predicate. I did not find such,

2) You answer is correct. You encapsulated it - so usage is one line. And the usage is important when talking about easiness - not the implementation, Consider to take some effort to remove this annoying typename from usage line. Maybe your assign_element<> shall derive from mpl::insert<>? Or consider to use "using" in C++11 way to remove typedef...

3) I would recommend this last answer: Ask MPL Author(s) to add something called replace_at...

HTH,
Piotr Nycz

Comment: Using `typename [...]::type` when invoking a metafunction is idiomatic, so I don't really see this as a default of the OP's implementation: until MPL authors decide to use template aliases to remove the need for this ugly syntax, it is better (IMHO) to stick with it, in order to be consistent. I agree with the rest of your answer though.

Comment: @LucTouraille You are right, I did not notice that `typename` is requireed for MPL stuff too.

Comment: @PiotrNycz Thanks for answering! At the beginning, I tried to use some predefined algorithm like MPL.fold but after a while a realized that I needed in any case to create an 'assign_at_pos' meta-function somewhere. Probably, the most efficient (compile-wise) way to achieve this is just defining n*(n+1)/2 partial specializations to handle all cases up to a vector length of n... In this case boost.preprocessor is you friend! I actually needed to do this to convert the actual return type of assign_element back to a vector_c...